# How to extract data from 'Column D' to one single column in a different sub sheet?

Tags: google-sheets

I've attached the sheet - [Click here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1p1HtLCvkqMtP8-AwViMosWChjT-BNr5SdeiPBKo7WbA/edit?usp=sharing)

I want pull data from these three sheets - A, B, C to this sheet - 'Combined data of Column D' and only the data in Column D would be pulled.

Anyone who can guide a newbie on how to do this? It'd be much appreciated!

Comment: Please include sample data within the question - linking to a file has to be avoided as no one will download it without knowing you. Furthermore you should show us what you already tried or where you have problems. Read [ask] and [repro] - this might help you to improve your question.

Comment: try this `=query({A!D:D;B!D:D;'C'!D:D},"where Col1 is not null")`

Answer (score 1):

use:

```
=QUERY({A!D:D; B!D:D; C!D:D}; "where Col1 is not null"; 0)
```

Comment: Thanks a ton! What should I do in the case where there are 100s of such sheets with complex names on every sheet. How do I create a similar formula for that?

Comment: @Manas you will need to manually add each sheet into array - thats the only non-scripted way of doing this task